# Как убрать пустые строки из словаря при сохранение в Excel (openpyxl)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

есть файл с которого читаю строки:
200
201
202
205

Имею список словарей, хочу значение которое есть в файле найти в списке словаре и сохранить в Excel но, в результате получаю еще много пустых строк в файле Excel, как это исправить? Хотя при печати из терминала пустых строк нет.

```
count = 2
    for res_print in persons_list: #Цикл списка словарей
        for res_load_tel in data_load_tel: #Цикл из файла
            if res_load_tel in res_print['tel']:
                ws['A' + str(count)] = str(res_print['user']).replace('[]','')
                ws['B' + str(count)] = str(res_print['dept']).replace('[]','')
                ws['C' + str(count)] = str(res_print['tel']).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')
                ws['D' + str(count)] = str(res_print['login']).replace('[]','')
                ws['E' + str(count)] = str(res_print['email']).replace('[]','')
                ws['F' + str(count)] = str(res_print['location']).replace('[]','')
                ws['G' + str(count)] = str(res_print['office']).replace('[]','')
    
        count += 1
    
    #Сохраняем файл
    wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Какие-то костыли тут: `.replace('[]','')`, `.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')`. Наверное, вам нужен метод строки `join`, но лучше опишите данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Костыли по замене,  [{'tel':[..., ....,]}]

Comment: Эта задача элементарно решается в Pandas, но без примеров входных данных и ожидаемого результата вряд ли кто-то захочет тратить свое время впустую и давать вам ответ, который вам скорее всего не подойтет из-за особенности данных...

Comment: Зачем pandas если это я думаю и так решаемо

Comment: Я же говори, что данные я получаю, но есть пустые строки, так это выборка из списка словарей persons_list, там где ранее были данные стало None